# Should [coauthors] be a synonym of [authorship]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed that there are two highly similar but distinct tags on the main site:

1. [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship), which has 893 questions, and [co-authors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-authors), [autorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autorship), and [equal-authors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equal-authors) as synonyms.
2. [coauthors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coauthors), which has 25 questions, no tag description, and no synonyms.

Since [co-authors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-authors) is a synonym of [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship), I think that either:

1. [coauthors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coauthors) should be made a synonym of [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship) (this seems most appropriate); or
2. [co-authors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-authors) and [coauthors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coauthors) should be made synonyms of each other, with neither being a synonym of [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship).

Comment: I have now made [tag:coauthors] synonym of [tag:authorship].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your option 1 seems the most appropriate. Here, questions about co-authors are essentially questions about authorship, and I can hardly see a description of [co-authors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-authors) sufficiently different from that of [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship): I would thus consider 2 not a good option.

Moreover, the description of [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship) already explicitly mentions problems of co-authorship:

> Queries related to academic authorship, i.e., who should be an author, the order of authors, or special roles such as corresponding authorship.